# How to post form data and html table data from a view to controller using Model in MVC4 .net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax, html-table

I have tried alot of things 
like

```
"var htmlTableValue = "<HTML>
<table>
 <tr><TD> 12 <TD></tr>
   </table>
   </HTML>";

      var request = $.ajax({
            url: '',//action method url which defined in controller
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: JSON.stringify(htmlTableValue),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        });`enter code here`"
```

but its not working even this answer on stackoverflow is marked as right answered. Actualy I what i want to do is have a html table in my view add rows on front end and at the end on save button save whole data from the view like i have some input text box too in my view.here is my code

```
       @model MyPumpERP.Models.SalesOrder
         @{
         Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Business.cshtml";
         ViewBag.Title = "New sales Contract";
          }
   <!DOCTYPE html>



   <html lang="en">
     <head>
   <script src="~/Assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Assets/css/PrintArea.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <script src="~/Assets/js/jquery.PrintArea.js"></script>
     </head>
       <body >
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="fax" class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="text-align:left">@Resources.Resource.Fax</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="7" placeholder="+111-000-999">
                                    </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="form-group">
                                   <label for="cellphone" class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="text-align:left">@Resources.Resource.CellPhone</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="8" placeholder="+111-000-999">
                                   </div>
                              </div>
                           <div class="form-group">
                                   <label for="Currency" class="col-sm-6 control-label" style="text-align:left">@Resources.Resource.Currency</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="9" placeholder="0000">
                                   </div>
                              </div>

                </div>
                  </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="table" class="table-editable">
                       <span class="table-add glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>


                    <table class="table">
                                        <tr>
                                           <th>@Resources.Resource.Project</th>
                                           <th>@Resources.Resource.Brand</th>
                                            <th>@Resources.Resource.Model</th>
                                           <th>@Resources.Resource.Name</th>
                                            <th>@Resources.Resource.Quantity</th>
                                           <th>@Resources.Resource.Unit</th>
                                            <th>@Resources.Resource.PriceCost</th>
                                           <th>@Resources.Resource.SubTotal</th>
                                           <th></th>
                                           <th></th>
                                           </tr>
                           @foreach (var item in Model.productdetail)
                 {

                                   <tr>
                           <td contenteditable="true">@item.ProductName</td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">
                                 <select class="currentCulture form-control" >

                                      <option value="0" title="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/flag_En.png")">1</option>
                                      <option value="1" title="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/flag_Ro.png")" selected="selected">2</option>
                                      <option value="2" title="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/flag_De.png")">3</option>

                                 </select>

                             </td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">@item.Name</td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">@item.Id</td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">@item.Model</td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">@item.Unit</td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">@item.Price</td>
                             <td contenteditable="true">@item.Type</td>
                             <td>
                                   <span class="table-remove fa fa-times-circle"></span>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                             <span class="table-up fa fa-sort-asc"></span>
                            <span class="table-down fa fa-sort-desc"></span>
                              </td>
                              </tr>

  <!-- This is our clonable table line -->
                           <tr class="hide">
                                 <td contenteditable="true">Untitled</td>
                                <td contenteditable="true">  
                                    <select class=" form-control" >

                                        <option value="0" title="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/flag_En.png")">1</option>
                                       <option value="1" title="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/flag_Ro.png")" selected="selected">2</option>
                                       <option value="2" title="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/flag_De.png")">3</option>

                        </select></td>
                               <td contenteditable="true">Untitled</td>
                                <td contenteditable="true">undefined</td>
                               <td contenteditable="true">Untitled</td>
                                <td contenteditable="true">undefined</td>
                               <td contenteditable="true">Untitled</td>
                                <td contenteditable="true">undefined</td>
                                <td>
                                <span class="table-remove fa fa-times-circle"></span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <span class="table-up fa fa-sort-asc"></span>
                                <span class="table-down fa fa-sort-desc"></span>
                                </td>
                           </tr>
                             }    
                     </table> 

                   </div>


                </div>
```

Productdetail is list type of product which i have in salesorder model.
I will Be very thank full if any body can help me out.

here is my Model

```
public class SalesOrder
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string SalesOrderId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> SalesOrderDeatilId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> SalesOrdertrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> OfficeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> EmployeeId { get; set; }
    //detail

    public string ShippingAddress { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public string CurrencyType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> SubTotal { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Total { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Quantity { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ProductId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public List<Product> productdetail { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like because you are just converting the table to JSON, you aren't necessarily going to be posting back the Model that you have said. In addition it's not really a form that you are posting. I am not able to test this at the moment but I recommend trying two things. The first is that you try changing the argument on your ActionResult to not be

**Early Assumptions (History)**

Can you provide the Method in the controller?

Is it decorated with the following attribute?

```
[HttpPost]
```

Or is the question not that you can't post, but that you can't post the table? If that is the case I recommend you look at how your model is setup - can you edit the main post with your Model as well please.

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult NewSalesContract(FormCollection formCollection) 
{
 ...
}
```

Or

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult NewSalesContract(List<string> model) 
{
 ...
}
```

And see if they have any values. However I don't recommend using these even if they work but instead making a strongly typed model of what you expect to get back, and then you can use something like the original signature.

Perhaps checking the value of the data that gets posted (JSON) and then making a model to match?

Comment: Yes I do

""""""""""
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewSalesContract(SalesOrder newsale)
        {}
""""
newsales have data of input feilds about like contract  number but bot have productdetail collection

Comment: I posted my model too

Comment: FormCollection will never gona work. because I need multiple rows data added on front end.

Comment: Then try the other option and if not that, do a console log on this JSON.stringify(htmlTableValue) and then make a model based off what you get back :) If you want - post it in an edit (alert me via comment) and I will help you model it into something

Comment: Thank you very much Glitc100 I am trying these options. :) will tell you when done .Once again bundles of thanks :)